# Добавить в массив все возможные значения бумерангов и записать их в массив и вывести

Tags: javascript

```
const items = [{a:1,b:3,c:1},{a:3,b:5,c:3},{a:5,b:5,c:5}]

function search (arr, value) {
    let boomerangs = []
    for (const item of arr) {
        if (item.a === item.c && item.b !== item.c) boomerangs.push(item);
    }
    return boomerangs
};
console.log(search(items,))
```

Надо это немного переделать, но не знаю как подойти к этому.
В общем оно должно из множества разных чисел из массива делать бумеранг и записывать его в другой массив.

Comment: Возможно, там откуда Вы родом, `бумеранг` это общепринятое понятие из мира программирования. Я же такого понятия никогда не встречал и большинство из моих коллег тоже. Поэтому что Вам нужно совершенно непонятно. Постарайтесь описать в задаче то, что вам нужно четко и ясно, без использования устойчивых и прочих выражений, которые могут быть поняты неоднозначным образом.

Comment: @Михаил Ребров, судя по всему, если a, b, c имеют одно значение, то это "палка". Если b отличается от a и c - это "бумеранг" :))

Comment: @puhh, У вас определена функция search с двумя параметрами. А запускается она почему-то с одним. Зачем value? Сама функция вроде бы работает нормально. Если, конечно, я правильно понял, что такое бумеранг:)))

Comment: @AndreySemykin, я тоже могу предложить. Но в том и дело что никто не должен гадать